# Gatsby React + Strapi: TypeError: result.data.allStrapiArticles.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby, strapi

I recently upgraded to the Strapi's new v4 only to find that the new way in which it was returning data was breaking my Gatsby app.

The new structure includes nested arrays within the data, and I am having trouble using this with Gatsby's createPages feature.

Here is the working query from http://localhost:8000/___graphql

```
query MyQuery {
  allStrapiArticles {
    edges {
      node {
        data {
          attributes {
            title
            author
            content
          }
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is what gets returned by that query (note each item and its relevant data now being in the arrays):

```
{
  "data": {
    "allStrapiArticles": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "data": [
              {
                "attributes": {
                  "title": "Test Title",
                  "author": "Test Author",
                  "content": "Test Content"
                },
                "id": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

The code exporter from http://localhost:8000/___graphql suggests the code block below to use with their createPages feature, however using it returns the following error :

> TypeError: result.data.allStrapiArticles.forEach is not a function

```
const path = require(`path`)

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const result = await graphql(`
    {
      allStrapiArticles {
        edges {
          node {
            data {
              attributes {
                title
                author
                content
              }
              id
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  const templatePath = path.resolve(`PATH/TO/TEMPLATE.js`)
  
  result.data.allStrapiJobs.forEach((node) => {
    createPage({
      path: `/careers/${node.id}`,
      component: path.resolve(`src/templates/article/index.js`),
      context: {
        slug: node.id,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

For reference, prior to upgrading to Strapi V4 my code block within gatsby-node.js using the createPages feature was as follows (note the data was returned without arrays and was far easier to work with):

```
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const path = require(`path`)
  const { createPage } = actions

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    graphql(`
      query {
        allStrapiArticles {
          edges {
            node {
              id
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `).then(result => {
      result.data.allStrapiArticles.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
        createPage({
          path: `/articles/${node.id}`,
          component: path.resolve(`src/templates/article/index.js`),
          context: {
            id: node.id,
          },
        })
      })
      resolve()
    })
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
    reject()
  })
}

const path = require(`path`)
const makeRequest = (graphql, request) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Query for nodes to use in creating pages.
    resolve(
      graphql(request).then(result => {
        if (result.errors) {
          reject(result.errors)
        }
        return result
      })
    )
  })
```

Does anyone more knowledgeable than I know how to get this working again? It has been a source of quite a lot of frustration. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`result.data.allStrapiArticles` is an object with a property `edges` which is an array of objects.

So, you have to iterate on `edges` prop:

```
result.data.allStrapiArticles.edges.forEach
```